# How to push to gitlab with multiple account?

Tags: git, push, gitlab

I set up in `~/.ssh/config` like this :

```
#Account one
Host one.gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#Account two
Host two.gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mastersystem
```

Then I try testing it like this : [image]

It's success

Note :

name 1 = moses toh, username 2 = moschel (I made this account about 2 years ago)

name 2 = moses, username 2 = moses639 (I made this account yesterday)

Then I try push to gitlab

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "test push multiple account"
3. git remote add moschel https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/myproject
4. git push --set-upstream moschel development

There is exist error like this :

```
remote: Access denied
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/myproject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Then I try again push to gitlab using another account

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "test push multiple account"
3. git remote add moses639 https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/myproject
4. git push --set-upstream moses639 development

There is exist error like this :

```
remote: Access denied
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/myproject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first your test is wrong. The point is not to give the identity file with the command, but by hostname, so try `ssh git@one.gitlab.com` and `ssh git@two.gitlab.com` and you should be greeted with different names. Your SSH config looks good from a quick glance.

The other point is, you say "try push" and "try push with another account" but you don't do. If you think that `git remote add moses639 https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/myproject` will push as user `moses639` this is totally wrong, because that is just the local name of your configured remote you can name it `foo` and it would still make no difference.

Furthermore, you use `https` URLs. This is not helpful if you want to select the identity by SSH config file. You have to clone (or actually push) via SSH protocol and then not with using `gitlab.com` as hostname, but `one.gitlab.com` or `two.gitlab.com`, depending on which identity you want to use. Actually you can use `gitlab.com` and `two.gitlab.com`, because `one.gitlab.com` identifies with the default key anyway.

Comment: `#Account one
Host ssh git@one.gitlab.com
    HostName one.gitlab.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#Account two
Host ssh git@two.gitlab.com
    HostName two.gitlab.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mastersystem`

Comment: if you mean the config be set like that? you try to give answers in detail, let me be more easily understood

Comment: No, I said the config looks fine, but you don't use it. You add a remote URL starting with `https://gitlab.com/`, while you should use SSH URLs `git@one.gitlab.com:...` and `git@two.gitlab.com:...`.